# Is Scaleform/Flash used in console games for non-UI, game elements?

Tags: flash, software-engineering, console, actionscript

I work for Konami as a Flash developer, and got sent some code for a puzzle mini-game from a new, yet-to-be-released Silent Hill game for PS3/Xbox 360.  It was a windows executable, but it was made in Flash, and I saw some GFX (Scaleform) libraries in the source.  I was very surprised by this, as I thought the extent of Flash's reach into console games was simply for UI.  Granted, this was an essentially 2d, UI-centric puzzle minigame, but nonetheless, this was a gameplay useage of Flash/Scaleform in a "next-gen" console title.

My question is, how prevalent is this?  I really want to get into console programming, and if this is something that appears elsewhere, maybe I can apply my Flash/Actionscript skills to getting a job working on console titles.  Anyone have any thoughts or experiences with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question isn't "Is it used?" (it is, even stuff like menus and whatnot are non-trivial bits of AS code in many games), but "How much?". Unless you have some UI/UX experience it may be somewhat difficult to find a job as a dedicated Scaleform person. Even if a team needs to make a minigame like that, it might be a week or two of work at the most, no need to have a dedicated person just for that when their normal UI programmer can handle it just fine. Read up on UX topic, maybe take some classes in HCI, then you will probably be in a better position to leverage your skills.